# Need to get all the label contents in an array from a parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the following example http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/FBcKP/

I have a `div` like this

```
<div id="test">
  <label>aaaaaaaaaaaa</label>
  <label>bbbbbbbbbbbb</label>
  <label>cccccccccccc</label>
  <label>dddddddddddd</label>
</div>
```

And the jquery i have written to get the contents is here

```
var values = $('#test').find('label').text()
```

I need to get the `values` as an array containing aaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbb,ccccccccc,ddddddddd
How to do that using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` method.

```
var arr = $('#test label').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
   // return this.textContent || this.innerText
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekAB5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append` to do this

```
var values = $('#test').find('label').append(",").text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FBcKP/1/